# Android Service onstart() getting called only after onCreate() of the calling activity ends

Tags: java, android

I am trying to start a service from the onCreate() of the launcher activity.

I created an intent object and called startService(). Does this will invoke service in new thread? I can see onStartCommand of the service is invoked only after the onCreate() of the activity exits.

Is this true ? If yes how to start a service parallely, i.e. oncreate can continue to exit in parallel with the onStartCommand of the service.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: startService() in application class

Comment: Can you please share a sample code link

Comment: @HiteshGehlot Why the downvote. I guess this is bound to be asked by anyone starting android. Not mentioned in any of the docs.

Comment: i not down vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this will invoke service in new thread?

In Java, objects do not run on threads. Methods run on threads.

> I can see onStartCommand of the service is invoked only after the onCreate() of the activity exits.

Correct. `startService()` merely queues a request to start the service. Android cannot do that until you return control of the main application thread to the framework. So long as `onCreate()` is running, you are tying up the main application thread. You need to make sure that each callback (e.g., `onCreate()`) is *very, very fast*, ideally well under 1 millisecond in duration.

> If yes how to start a service parallely, i.e. oncreate can continue to exit in parallel with the onStartCommand of the service.

That is not possible, sorry.

Comment: Thanks. That confirms my doubts.